VBA for each loop doesn't repeat itself for every element (i.e. all emails of an outlook folder)
The code below is a very simplified version of the actual one and theoretically puts every email of outlook folder "Test" into folder "Test1". Practically, I need to prompt it a few times until every email is sorted away (even if the folder contains only 5 emails).
What could I change so that the loop doesn't stop until there are no more objects in the folder?
 Sub TestLoop()
    
    Dim olApp       As Outlook.Application
    Dim objNS       As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim olFolder    As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim inmsg       As Object
    
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
    Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set olFolder = objNS.Folders("x@y.com").Folders("Test")
    Set olMessages = olFolder.Items
    Set myDestFolder1 = objNS.Folders("x@y.com").Folders("Test1")
    
    For Each inmsg In olMessages
        inmsg.Move myDestFolder1
    Next inmsg
    
End Sub


What do you mean by having to "prompt" it? Is there a message and if so, what does it say?

When removing items from a collection in a loop, typically it's a good idea to loop backwards over the collection.  For i= olMessages.Count To 1 Step -1 for example
